# Pattern recognition in Pandas column(s)

Tags: python, pandas

I dont know if stackoverflow isn't the right place to post this, if isn't please tell me an alternative.

I have a dataset where i want to classify the data in a "opmerking" (opmerking = comment ) column. I've created a dummy data set to explain what i mean.

[image]
each number represents a byte where each bit means something else. So i have a script which takes the most important bits from those bytes and that dataset looks like this:

[image]

The bytes/bits are to indicate cycles of a piece of equipment and i need to detect where a cycle isn't normal. 
So far i can detect rows where abnormal behaviour is happening but I would like the full cycle.

this is the code i use for finding abnormalities in the Bit data:

```
dfphotocells = dfsamen[(dfsamen.closeout == 0) & (dfsamen.openout == 0) & (dfsamen.limitswitchopen == 0) & (dfsamen.limitswitchclose == 0) & (dfsamen.prelimit == 0) & (dfsamen.photocells == 1) & (dfsamen.lampgroen == 1) & (dfsamen.lamprood == 1) & (dfsamen.halfopen == 0 ) & (dfsamen["DateTime"]>='2018-06-1 00:00:00') & (dfsamen["DateTime"]<='2018-10-10 00:00:00')]
dfphotocells['opmerking'] = 'photocells'
```

this obviously only gives me the rows where photocells = 1.

I was thinking of using a naive bayes classifier but i don't know how accurate that would be.

So my full question is: 
Should i look at my cycles bytewise or bitwise and which method should I use for detecting a full cycle? (i am not looking for someone to code this for me, just a nudge in the right direction)

Comment: first you need to decide what are your output classes and then use the bytewise data as features to classify the test/new records into any of these classes. You can use a multinomial logistic regression to achieve this.

Comment: Martin, First of all this image data dont really helpful, better you can paste initial 10 lines of the data to showcase here which will be easy to read, However you can also add if you have done something so far .

Comment: I wanted to paste the data in text but that came out messy and more unreadable imo and i needed to show more than 10 lines to display what i mean.

Comment: I've added a line of code that i use to find the abnormalities, but they only show me one or two rows where that is the case. I am looking for a way where the comment/opmerking applies to the whole cycle.

Comment: multinomial logistic regression looks like it might work, thanks for the suggestion